# Compare a DOM innerHTML value with an object property

Tags: javascript, object, comparison

```
var metric ={
                      temp: data.main.temp,
                      celsius: "&#x2103;",
                      fahr: "&#x2109;",
                      toCelsius: function(){
                      var convert = this.temp- 273.15;
                          return Math.ceil(convert) + this.celsius;
                    },
                      toFahr: function(){
                      var convert = (this.temp * 1.8)- 459.67;
                          return Math.ceil(convert) + this.fahr;
                    }
                  }

 <div id="temp">
        <h2>Temperature</h2>
        <p id="tempApp" class="btn btn-default">26&#x2103;</p></div>
```

How do I compare the $("#temp").innerHTML's value with the metric.toCelsius value?

I tried running the code below but It never worked.

```
                        var state1 = metric.toCelsius();
                        var state2 = metric.toFahr();
                        var div =  document.getElementById("tempApp"
                        if(div.innerHTML == state1){
                            console.log("yes")
                        }
                         else{
                             alert("error")
                         }
```

Comment: Do `parseInt(document.getElementById("tempApp").innerText, 10)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that innerHTML will transpose the HTML Entity code to the actual celsius symbol. So it might be easier to convert the string to a number (via `parseFloat`) before you compare.

The better option is to convert the HTML Entity to a string before comparing.

Here are both options:

```js
                  // I hard-coded `temp` for this example
                  var metric = {
                      temp: 300,
                      celsius: "&#x2103;",
                      fahr: "&#x2109;",
                      toCelsius: function(){
                          var convert = this.temp - 273.15;
                          return Math.ceil(convert);
                      },
                      toFahr: function(){
                          var convert = (this.temp * 1.8) - 459.67;
                          return Math.ceil(convert);
                    }
                  };
    
                  var div =  document.getElementById('tempApp');
                  console.log('See the innerHTML: ', div.innerHTML);

                  // Option 1: parse the text and hope for the best
                  var temp = parseFloat(div.innerHTML);
    
                  if (temp === metric.toCelsius()) {
                      console.log('Matched number!');
                  } else {
                      console.log('No match number');
                  }

                  // Option 2: convert to a string and compare
                  var sliced = metric.celsius.slice(3);
                  var num = parseInt(sliced, 16); 
                  var str = String.fromCharCode(num);

                  if (div.innerHTML === metric.toCelsius() + str) {
                      console.log('Matched string!');
                  } else {
                      console.log('No match string');
                  }
```

```html
<div id="temp">
        <h2>Temperature</h2>
        <p id="tempApp" class="btn btn-default">27&#x2103;</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @lamlimo Welcome to StackOverflow! It sounds like you should use my first option for matching the number if you don't care about the units. If you are still having problems, you should post the source code that doesn't work.